# How to set Jenkins environment variables in run-time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I want to set some jenkins environment variables in run time based on my computation. How can i set this run-time in my jenkinsfile's `step` section.

for example: based on my calculation i get `abc=1`. How can i set this in real time in my jenkinsfile's `step` section so that i can use it later by calling `$abc`.

I am declaring my pipeline and environment variables as explained here:
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/

i'm using Jenkins ver. 2.41

Answer (score 1):

Here an example how to set variables and use it in the same Jenkinsfile.
The Variable versionToDeploy will be used by the `build job` step.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'build the artifacts'
                script {
                    versionToDeploy = '2.3.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        success { 
            echo 'start deploy job'
            build job: 'pipeline-declarative-multi-job-deploy', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'version', value: versionToDeploy]]
        }
    }
}
```